# I can not create a folder and keep getting "mkdir(): No such file or directory" error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am simply trying to create a folder. I want to create the folder in this folder:

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs\LaravelProject\public\storage\uploads\albums
```

so in the end I want to have:

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs\LaravelProject\public\storage\uploads\albums\albumName
```

I've been trying to accomplish that using:

```
    public function uploadAlbum(Request $request){
        $name = $request['albumName'];
        File::makeDirectory(storage_path('public/uploads/albums/' . $name));
    }
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
"mkdir(): No such file or directory"
```

Comment: Check the value returned by `storage_path('public/uploads/albums')`. Most probably it doesn't return what you think but a path that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [public_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-public-path) method instead

```
File::makeDirectory(public_path('storage/uploads/albums/'.$name));
```